# Meteor Deploy to DigitalOcean

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-up

I'm trying to deploy my meteor project to DigitalOcean with meteor-up (mup)

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      // TODO: set host address, username, and authentication method
      host: '142.93.59.204',
      username: 'root',
      pem: '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
      // password: 'server-password'
      // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  app: {
    // TODO: change app name and path
    name: 'MyAppName',
    path: '../',

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      PORT: 8001,
      ROOT_URL: 'http://142.93.59.204',
      MONGO_URL: My Mongo URL,
      MONGO_OPLOG_URL: Mongo oplog url,
      UNIVERSE_I18N_LOCALES: 'all'
    },

    docker: {
      // change to 'abernix/meteord:base' if your app is using Meteor 1.4 - 1.5
      image: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base',
    },

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  //mongo: {
   // version: '3.4.1',
   // servers: {
    //  one: {}
  //  }
//  },

  // (Optional)
  // Use the proxy to setup ssl or to route requests to the correct
  // app when there are several apps

  // proxy: {
  //   domains: '142.93.201.135',
  //   ssl: {
  //     // Enable let's encrypt to create free certificates.
  //     // The email is used by Let's Encrypt to notify you when the
  //     // certificates are close to expiring.
  //     letsEncryptEmail: ''
  //   }
  // }
};
```

After mup setup I didn't get any errors, and also after mup deploy was successful.
But when I try to open my app from browser with my server ip 142.93.59.204, it's don't open nothing.
The server on digitalocean on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: is the ip open to internet?

Comment: I just registred in digitalocean and made a new droplet, should I do any operations?

Comment: Check your control panel to make sure http is open. You can ssh into the box and do a `docker ps` to make sure the processes are running

Comment: I have fixed it, the issue reason was ssl package in meteor